# how can i use case statement after using left join?

Tags: sql-server, case, hierarchy

```
select t1.Name, t1.[Code], t2.Name as ParentName
      ,case when len(t2.[ParentCode]) = '' then t1.[Code] else t2.[ParentCode] end as t1.[ParentCode]
      ,case when len([Descr])=0 then [Code] else [Descr] end as [Descr]
      ,t1.[Cumulative]
      ,t1.[Expense]
      ,t1.[Accts]
      ,t1.[Admin]
      ,t1.[Assessment]
      ,t1.[Balance]
      ,t1.[Fiber]
      ,t1.[GL]
      ,t1.[LV]
      ,t1.[Slush]
from [KR].[pl].[Accounts] as t1
left join [KR].[pl].[Accounts] t2 on t1.ParentCode = t2.ParentCode
```

I am trying to use case statement to fill out the blank columns, before i used left join, it work fine, but after i use the left join its not working anymore. Is there anyway to work those case statement with left join?

Comment: what were you using before using left join? what is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing fundamental that prevents a `CASE` statement working with a `LEFT (OUTER) JOIN`, but the important thing to remember about OUTER joins is that there may be NULL values in the outer table.

Your `CASE` statements as written don't account for that, e.g. (assuming that [Descr] could be NULL), in your statement:

> case when len([Descr])=0 then [Code] else [Descr] end as [Descr]

`len([Descr])` will evaluate to NULL, not zero, if [Descr] is NULL, and therefore fall through to the `ELSE` clause of the `CASE`, returning the NULL field anyway.

The correct way to write that using `CASE` would be:

```
CASE WHEN len(IsNull([Descr], '')) = 0 THEN [Code] ELSE [Descr] END AS [Descr]
```

But there's an easier way, using the `Coalesce` function:

```
Coalesce([Descr], [Code]) AS [Descr]
```

[MSDN on Coalesce says:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190349.aspx)

> Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the
>   first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL.

So your query becomes:

```
select t1.Name, t1.[Code], t2.Name as ParentName
      ,Coalesce(t2.[ParentCode], t1.[Code]) AS [ParentCode]
      ,Coalesce([Descr], [Code]) AS [Descr]         
      ,t1.[Cumulative]
      ,t1.[Expense]
      ,t1.[Accts]
      ,t1.[Admin]
      ,t1.[Assessment]
      ,t1.[Balance]
      ,t1.[Fiber]
      ,t1.[GL]
      ,t1.[LV]
      ,t1.[Slush]
from [KR].[pl].[Accounts] as t1
left join [KR].[pl].[Accounts] t2 on t1.ParentCode = t2.ParentCode
```

**EDIT:** One thing to add - if your values for [ParentCode] or [Descr] could be a zero-length string (''), and you want to return the other field in that case too, then write the Coalesce statements like so:

```
Coalesce(NullIf(t2.[ParentCode], ''), t1.[Code]) AS [ParentCode]
Coalesce(NullIf([Descr], ''), [Code]) AS [Descr]
```

The [NullIf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177562.aspx) function does kind of the opposite to Coalesce, returning NULL if the two expressions are equal, else the first one.